# docker run -it gcr.io/... /bin/bash does not get SkyDNS settings in /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

From a running pod on a GKE node I can:

```
# docker exec e68f1765f8b0 more /etc/resolv.conf 
::::::::::::::
/etc/resolv.conf
::::::::::::::
nameserver 10.103.240.10
nameserver 169.254.169.254
nameserver 10.10.0.1
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local c.dandsltd-gce.internal. 899692696219.google.internal. google.internal.
options ndots:5
```

But from the same GKE node, if I run:

```
# docker run  -it gcr.io/<same image> /bin/bash
root@ac81b13b172d:/# more /etc/resolv.conf 
domain c.dandsltd-gce.internal.
search c.dandsltd-gce.internal. 899692696219.google.internal. google.internal.
nameserver 169.254.169.254
nameserver 10.10.0.1
```

This threw me for a loop cause I thought SkyDNS was not running on my containers.  Obviously, starting a pod/container from the replication controller is doing more stuff, like injecting the SkyDNS settings vs just a docker run.

Is there a way to run a one off docker container and get the same environment as a container started via the replication controller?

Thanks,
Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I really just needed to do was:

```
# docker exec e68f1765f8b0 bash
```

frmo the GKE node.  Then I could get a shell from a container running in the cluster instead of a new container just running locally but not provisioned by kubernetes.

This way, something like SkyDNS is setup for you and you can test something like 
    wget .default.cluster.local 
etc

Answer (score 0):

You can run a one off container by creating a pod with `restartPolicy: Never` in the spec. Example:

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
  restartPolicy: "Never"`

With v1.1, kubectl will support creating one-off pods from an image via `kubectl run $podname --image=$image --restart=Never`. In the meantime, you have to create a pod from a file to specify restart policy.